# Regex querystring-like string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following two examples:

`'123?type=hand' ===> 'type'`

`'123?type=hand&status=alive'` ===> 'type status'

In english I want: Find the `?` and remove everything in front.
Find `=` and remove everything after it until the `&`.

In the end of the day what I want is just either a string, array, whatever of the actual queryStringVariableNames. Not any of the values.

I think I'm over complexifying it. :)

Here is a couple snippets I have been working with:

```
var pattern = /\*(\?)|\*(\&)|(\=)\*/ig;
var pattern = /(.+?\?)/g;

str.replace(pattern, function (matcher, positionOfMatch, item) {
            return '';
});
```

I started using the longform of `replace` so I could see better what was going on.

**EDIT**

My exact implementation ended up being the following:

```
function (str) {
  str = str.substr(str.indexOf('?') + 1);

  return str.split('&')
            .map(function (i) {
               return i.substr(0, i.indexOf('='))
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to just use string operations instead of regular expressions. This gives you an array with the keys in the string:

```js
var str = '123?type=hand&status=alive';

str = str.substr(str.indexOf('?') + 1);
var keys = str.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  keys[i] = keys[i].substr(0, keys[i].indexOf('='));
}

// Show in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(keys));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
var result = str.split("?")[1].split("&");
```

So if your string is `123?foo=bar&one=something&nothing=else`, you're getting an array of strings as a `result`: `foo=bar`, `one=something`, `nothing=else`.

Then the first parameter is accessible by `result[0]`, its key is accessible with `result[0].split("=")[0]` and its value is accessible with `result[0].split("=")[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this array and grab captured group #1:

```
/[?&]([^=]+)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT1sI1/7)

**Code:**

```
var str = '123?type=hand&status=alive';
var re = /[?&]([^=]+)/g; 
var m;
var result = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    result.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(result);
//=> ["type", "status"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for all instances of

```
(?:\?|&)([^\=]+)(?=\=)
```

by using the 'g' modifier.

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/mM4lR4/2